How to remove newsletter popup in SoapUi?
Every time I start SoapUI the following popup appears:
How do I get rid of this popup? I've tried looking through the settings, but can't find anything appropriate. I would like to have SoapUI start up without displaying the popup. I'm using version 5.7.2 of SoapUI.

How about adding this information? There are no free products so they want you to use ready API so they may keep on asking till you provide this information. if you don't want to provide right information add random names or a non-existing email id

Thanks for commenting. I have tried to add information but the popup still appears. The solution was apparently to just start creating some projects that were loaded at startup and the popup disappeared.

Apparently the popup disappears when you start to have a project and/or a workspace that are loaded on startup.
